# Write custom .htaccess file for routing

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want a `.htacccess` file, which will serve me a custom routing.

> E.g; whatever I put after slash with my domain (www.example.com/anything), 
>   it will redirect me to (www.example.com/index.html). Can anyone provide me this file?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: At Stack Overflow people will help you, but you need to write the code, it's not a code writing service

Comment: I know it's not code writing service, but I need this code for routing my project. If I have the code, then it's not necessary to write here and seeking help from you guys.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which explains how SO works. I'm sorry that it's not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> **You can try this :**
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> **OR**
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.(html|php) !-f
> RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/something-blew-up.html [R=302]
> ```